# Select Query with IS NULL and Values

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql

I am a beginner with PostgreSQL and this is a critical problem for me.

My table looks like this:

```
test num_1 num_2
0    1     1
1
2
```

Several columns in my database have NULL or non-NULL values. I want to read out `test` using just one query, which can accept NULL as well as non-NULL values.

The queries should have the functionality given below:

First query:

```
x = 1
sql = ("""SELECT test FROM table WHERE num_1 = %s""")
df = pd.read_sql(sql, con = db, params = (x))
```

It should return 0.

Second query:

```
x = None
sql = ("""SELECT test FROM table WHERE num_1 IS NULL""")
df = pd.read_sql(sql, con = db, params = (x))
```

It should return `1,2`.

How can achieve this using just one query? I tried the below code but it is not working correctly:

```
x = None
sql = ("""SELECT test FROM table WHERE num_1 = %s or num_1 IS NULL """)
df = pd.read_sql(sql, con = db, params = (x))
```

It returns `0,1,2`. I believe it is happening because of the "or" in the query. I want to have just one query that can handle or take both the NULL or a value.

If I query for NULL it should return `1,2`, and if I query for `1` it should return `0`. I do not want `0,1,2`.

Comment: What is your actual expected output?  Your third query is working as expected.

Comment: I want the same query to accept None and give me 1,2 or it should take 1 and return 0. I do not know what to change the query based on the input. Please let me know if you want me to clarify further. Thanks!

Comment: This makes no sense to me.  Do you want to match NULL or 1?

Comment: I want to write just 1 query that can handle NULL as well as 1. I will be using the same query in a loop. Example if I give NULL then I want my database to return matching column values. If the input is 1 then I should get 0 from the database. Since, I am using "or" in my query so, it returns 0,1,2. What is the alternative to using or?

Comment: You need `is not distinct from` instead of `=`, it can to handle both NULL and non NULL values: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html

Comment: Yes, `is not distinct from` worked. I also had to get rid of the `or` condition from the query. You are a life saver! @Abelisto

Comment: I don't see what is unclear about this question, so I'll vote for reopening it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a case for [`IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISON-PRED-TABLE) which is like an `=` that treats NULL as a normal value:

```
SELECT test FROM table WHERE num_1 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM %s
```

The down side is that this condition cannot use an index.

If you need to use an index, you could write

```
SELECT test FROM table WHERE num_1 = %s
UNION ALL
SELECT test FROM table WHERE num_1 IS NULL AND %s IS NULL
```